# Where's the Gemara about a woman ultra-multitasking?

Tags: sources-mekorot, maseches-kesubos

I thought – but forgive me, can't find it now – that the Gemara assumes if a husband provides for his wife, then he has the rights to minor earnings she makes from spinning or the like. The Gemara then asks what if she does multiple jobs at the same time? Some humorous example of spinning while doing singing lessons while keeping silk eggs warm ... something like that? Help me out, please; tell me I wasn't totally imagining this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kesubos 66A

> בָּעֵי רַב פָּפָּא עָשְׂתָה לוֹ שְׁתַּיִם בְּבַת אַחַת מַהוּ בָּעֵי רָבִינָא שְׁלֹשָׁה אוֹ אַרְבָּעָה בְּבַת אַחַת מַהוּ תֵּיקוּ

> Rav Pappa raises a dilemma: In a case where she performed two tasks for him simultaneously, what is the halakha; is the status of the earnings the same as surplus produced through exertion? Similarly, Ravina raises a dilemma: In a case where she performed three or four tasks simultaneously, what is the halakha? The dilemmas shall stand unresolved. (Sefaria)

Rashi explains the case of 3 or 4 at one time

> שתים שלש וארבע בבת אחת - שומרת קישואים וטווה פשתן ומלמדת שיר לנשים בשכר ומחממת ביצים בחיקה או ביצי תולעים העושים משי שהנשים מחממות אותן בחיקן והם נוצרים